# Always opening Main module instead of Product Flavour in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-productflavors

Hi I have two product flavour in my project.

```
1) Author Module (com.example.Author)
2) Teacher Module (com.example.Teacher)
```

And one in my `Main Module (com.example).`

All Module has separate mainfest file and in all mainfest file package name is "com.example".

**Structure::**

> For Author ::

```
app->src->author_module
                      ->java->com.example.author
                      ->res
```

> For Teacher ::

```
app->src->teacher_module
                      ->java->com.example.teacher
                      ->res
```

> For Main ::

```
app->src->Main
              ->java->com.example
              ->res
```

> build.gradle ::

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        teacher_module {
            minSdkVersion 21
            applicationId 'com.example.teacher'
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        author_module {
            minSdkVersion 21
            applicationId 'com.example.author'
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
    }

}
```

Now whether I select `author_module` or `teacher_module` in build variant. It always run `main_module`

[image]

and **also note that when I kill that app and open it again by clicking icon on device then it open selected variant** and also **I found four icons also on my device screen** . what is happening here?

Why my product flavour not running if I select flavour in my build variant.?